# Why is MSE score for GAM an NA value?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, mse

I am trying to compare the MSE values for two GAMs that are modeling water temperature. The only difference between the two is that one model has an auto-regressive (lag = 1) term. When I run the cross-validation, the MSE score for the auto-regressive model is NA and I cannot figure out why. I removed all the NA values from the dataset before running the CV. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

[image]

[image]